# Does Hawking radiation never happen because a black hole takes an infinite time to form?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, observers, hawking-radiation

Consider the classical solution of a black hole and imagine some matter crossing the event horizontal so that it cannot escape the black hole. I don't remember in the case of a rotating black hole, but in the simpler solution of a non rotating one, a distant observer should see this matter appear to slow down and freeze near the event horizon, never quite reaching it..I can't remember if the same is essentially true in a real back hole, i. e. one that rotates. If it were, and the physical picture were really that simple , then it would probably mean that from an external perspective,  not a single piece of matter has ever actually entered a black hole in all the time the universe has existed. Under intuitive causation  you might therefore not expect to actually observe Hawking Radiation, as to the external observer nothing will have reached the event horizon in all this time. Evidently this picture is wrong somehow.

So my question is: what is wrong with this simple picture that I have presented and why would we expect to see hawking radiation?

Comment: Hello Ben. Could you provide a link to the question if you think it was answered before, as that would be helpful..I did see a question that asks if black holes ever actually form. Note that I am not asking that question..I am also not asking if.Hawling radiation occurs. I am asking how can any observer ever actually see it. If you fall through the event horizon it is behind you and you won't see it. If you are a fixed observer outside the event horizontal, then no mass as yet ever fallen in, so you won't see. I don't see an answer to that specific question; how can you see it?

Comment: I found the question below that asks a similar question. The answer is as I would have expected and is probably the same answer to my own related question..I think the answer is that the classical solution is just an approximation and that time dilation will be large but finite.. So another way I could ask my question would be: would not hawking radiation be topossible red shifted ever to detect?